# php jquery Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, class

I am wanting to create grid using databases based off of a groupId. At the moment, I have everything calling the same query. My problem is when I select a group and use `jQuery` to post to my `Gateway.php` file. I created a `psuedo-MVC` setup. I separated 3 directory in Controller, Models, and Views. From this php file, I keep getting these error messages:

> Warning: require(Membership/Controllers/Members.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\xampp\htdocs\HelloWorld\Membership\Includes\Gateway.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Membership/Controllers/Members.php' (include_path='.;H:\xampp\php\PEAR') in H:\xampp\htdocs\HelloWorld\Membership\Includes\Gateway.php on line 11

So, I have tried several things. One, I move the call to the index.php and it worked great. But from the `jQuery` call, it gives me the errors.

I created another php file with a function in it. I moved my code from the model and the view. I had it return the html of the table with results. It works.

Can someone point me to an example of making a `jQuery` ajax call to a class function? Or give some direction.

---

Members.js

```
var Members = {
Display: function(groupId) {
    var pData = {
        action: 'GetMembers',
        groupId: groupId 
    };
    $("#crGroups").empty();
    $("#crGroups").append("Getting Members..." );  
    $.ajax({
        url: "Membership/Includes/Gateway.php",  
        type: "POST",        
        data: pData,     
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            try {
                var members = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (members !== undefined) {
                    $("#crGroups").empty();
                    $("#crGroups").append(members.html);       
                } else {
                    $("#crGroups").empty();
                    $("#crGroups").append(data);                   
                } 
            } catch (err){
               $("#crGroups").empty();
               $("#crGroups").append(data + "<br><br>Error description: " + err.message);                   
            }
        }       
    }); 
}
```

}

Gateway.php

```
<?php

$action = $_POST['action'];
$groupId = $_POST['groupId'];

$data = array();

// Gateway for processing
switch($action)  {
    case 'GetMembers' :   
        require  'Membership/Controllers/Members.php';
        $member = new MembersController();
        //include 'Members.php';
        $data["status"] = "success";
        $data["html"] = $member->GetMembers();
        //$data["html"] = getMembers();
        break;
    case 'AddMember' : 
        $page = 'Add Member'; 
        break;
    case 'page3' : 
        $data["status"] = "success"; 
        break;
    case 'page4' : 
        $data["status"] = "success"; 
        break;
    default :
        $data["status"] = "failure";
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: url: "Membership/Includes/Gateway.php" .. I think this will be wrong here .. since you are using pseudo mvc here so put the url here will will access your page Gateway.php .... like "http://yourDomain/xyz.." I was also stuck at such problem .. and working like this solved it.. hope it works for you too ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change

```
require  'Membership/Controllers/Members.php';
```

to

```
require  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'HelloWorld/Membership/Controllers/Members.php';
```

Comment: Thank both of you for the advice. It worked. I did have put this in my other files, but it solved the problem. I think I am going to define where I can use all over my files, and change it once. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank both of you for the advice. It worked. I did have put this in my other files, but it solved the problem. I think I am going to define where I can use all over my files, and change it once. Thanks again.